# Pandas - It is possible to capitalize words after quote (") symbol in column?

Tags: python, pandas

It is possible to capitalize words after quote (") symbol in a column?

Like the following:

Input:

```
A | B
1 | Hi "john"
2 | My "mother" lives with my "father
```

Output:

```
A | B
1 | Hi "John"
2 | My "Mother" lives with my "Father
```

I'm trying the next statement without success:

```
df['B'] = df['B'].apply('. '.join(map(lambda s: s.strip().title(), df['B'].astype(str).str.split('"')))
```

Comment: You can replace it with a regex, like: `df[col].str.replace('["].', lambda m: m[0].upper())`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks. What if quoted substring has multiple words like in "mr. owen".

Answer (score 1):

This should work with multiple words:

```
df['B'] = df['B'].str.replace(r'"(.+)"', lambda m: m.group(0).title())
```

If you need a more complex transformation - just define a custom function and insert it in place of `lambda m`.